# GTFS - all services for particular stop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gtfs

Crucial functionality of my app is to search bus stops by name which will return bus stop details as well as all services departing from it. I used php and MySQL and I was able to do so using GROUP_CONCAT. Now I'm planing to move to MS SQL and I did some initial work on this. I'm able to get all needed information using stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Latitude, Longitude, Url,
(SELECT [dbo].[RoutesForStopId](Id)) 'Routes'
            FROM Stops WHERE Stops.Name LIKE '%' + @Parameter + '%'
```

Where RoutesForStopId is scalar-valued function:

```
SELECT @Routes = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + r.ShortName FROM StopTimes st
            INNER JOIN trips t ON t.TripId = st.TripId
            INNER JOIN routes r ON r.Id = t.RouteId
            WHERE st.StopId = @StopId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM Stops WHERE Stops.Id = @StopId
```

It works as expected but response is very slow. I often get timeouts when calling this service.

Is there any way to speed up this query? I would appreciate a help on this as this is important piece of information for end user but being this slow I'm considering to get rid of this. It used to work much faster with MySQL db.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? 2017 has `string_agg()`

Comment: In addition, in order to speak about performance we need to see your full Execution Plan (XML and not image), and get the DDL of the relevant table(s)